# In R DT::datatable(), how to apply the same filters as those called by the filter argument to specific columns in an already defined header row?

Tags: javascript, html, r, datatables, dt

I am using the DT package in R but have been heavily supplementing it with added JavaScript. One of the arguments in DT::datatable() is filter, which adds sophisticated filters to each column depending on the data type (i.e. drop down menus for factors, interval sliders for numbers, etc.). I do not know how to replicate this kind of filter in code.

The problem of this option is that it creates an additional header row (filter="top"), or an additional footer row (filter="bottom"), exclusively for these filters. However, I desire to have a header row that includes both these sophisticated filters for some columns, and column names for the rest. The following images depict the achieved result and the desired result (as an image edit), respectively:

Achieved result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

The following example is as far as I've been able to go, based on someone else's code:
http://live.datatables.net/covokida/1/edit

However, this solution does not work for me for the following reasons:

1. The filter boxes lack the clean design of the desired result;
2. There is no possibility of selecting multiple fields (filtering for
   an "or" condition);
3. When the same initComplete function is applied to my case, there is
   no option to remove the applied filters (I don't know why).

I would love to know of a way I could either more directly apply the already defined sophisticated filters to whichever columns and in whichever position in the table I desire, or how to further modify the simpler ones in the example such that they address the shortcomings listed above.